# How to import an excel file into database without giving "create table ... " script using java

Tags: java, sql, database, reactive

I have to create a library that will be used by others to import data from an excel sheet into a database. 
The user will only give the name of excel file and the database connection. 
The library has to build a create table script and insert the data. The name of the table can be the same as the excel file name.

What is the best solution in java? Is there an api that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: `Is there an api to generate the create scripts? The library will have to sample first few records from excel to come with the best colymn data types`

Answer (score 0):

Below is what will do in this sense.

1. First, read and parse the excel data. [jxl](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or [poi](https://poi.apache.org/) library can do this.
2. If we can't read or parse excel, break flow
3. When parsed successfully, create the corresponding table by using the jdbc api or something like that. The table structure based on the excel sheet columns.
4. Then batch insert the parsed excel data into database.

Comment: The **crux** of the problem is to automate the -  _"create the corresponding table by using the jdbc api or something like that"_    
`Is there a library to generate the create scripts? The library will have to sample first few records from excel to come with the best colymn data types`

Comment: As far as i know, i'm afraid you need code this yourself. Actually it's not complex. At most case, we just need check the value should be quote or not. Cell type(which can get by `jxl` or `poi`) is useful to judge whether need quote value or not.